# What are futures and how are they different from options?

Tags: trading, options, terminology, futures, derivatives

As a form of investment there are contracts to buy commodities at a specific time in the future or at a specific price.  How is this different from an option to buy a share?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cart's answer is basically correct, but I'd like to elaborate:

A futures contract obligates **both** the buyer of a contract and the seller of a contract to conduct the underlying transaction (*settle*) at the agreed-upon future date and price written into the contract.

Aside from settlement, the only *other* way either party can get out of the transaction is to initiate a **closing transaction**, which means:  The party that sold the contract buys back another similar contract to close his position.  The party that bought the contract can sell the contract on to somebody else.

Whereas, an option contract provides the **buyer** of the option with the **choice** of completing the transaction.  Because it's a choice, the buyer can choose to walk away from the transaction if the option exercise price is not attractive relative to the underlying stock price at the date written into the contract.  When an option buyer walks away, the option is said to have *expired*.

However – and this is the part I think needs elaboration – the original seller (*writer*) of the option contract **doesn't have a choice.**  If a buyer chooses to exercise the option contract the seller wrote, the seller is **obligated** to conduct the transaction.  In such a case, the seller's option contract is said to have been *assigned*.  Only if the buyer chooses not to exercise does the seller's obligation go away.  Before the option expires, the option seller can close their position by initiating a closing transaction.  But, the seller can't simply walk away like the option *buyer* can.

Comment: You are absolutely correct Chris.  Thanks for the additional comments.

Answer (score 4):

For futures, you are obligated to puchase the security at $x when the contract expires.  For an option, you have the right or option to do so if it's favorable to you.